# The training loss of my PyTorch LSTM model does not decrease

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I am new in PyTorch and wanna customize an LSTM model for the MNIST dataset. Here is my 2-layer LSTM model for MNIST dataset. The first class is customized LSTM Cell and the second one is the LSTM model.

```
class Cust_LSTMCell(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, nlayers, dropout):
    """"Constructor of the class"""
    super(Cust_LSTMCell, self).__init__()

    self.nlayers = nlayers
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

    ih, hh = [], []
    for i in range(nlayers):
        ih.append(nn.Linear(input_size if i == 0 else hidden_size, 4 * hidden_size))
        hh.append(nn.Linear(hidden_size, 4 * hidden_size))
    self.w_ih = nn.ModuleList(ih)
    self.w_hh = nn.ModuleList(hh)
    self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()
    self.tanh = nn.Tanh()


def forward(self, input, hidden): # input shld be with shape (batch_size, input_size)
    """"Defines the forward computation of the LSTMCell"""
    hy, cy = [], []
    for i in range(self.nlayers):
        hx, cx = hidden[0][i], hidden[1][i]
        gates = self.w_ih[i](input) + self.w_hh[i](hx)
        i_gate, f_gate, c_gate, o_gate = gates.chunk(4, 1)

        i_gate = self.sig(i_gate)
        f_gate = self.sig(f_gate)
        c_gate = self.tanh(c_gate)
        o_gate = self.sig(o_gate)

        ncx = (f_gate * cx) + (i_gate * c_gate)
        nhx = o_gate * self.tanh(ncx)
        cy.append(ncx)
        hy.append(nhx)
        input = self.dropout(nhx)

    hy, cy = torch.stack(hy, 0), torch.stack(cy, 0)
    return hy, cy

class LSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
    super(LSTM, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.lstm = Cust_LSTMCell(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, 0)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
def forward(self, x): # x is a tensor with shape (sequence_length, batch_size, input_size)
    # Set initial hidden and cell states 
    hx = torch.zeros(num_layers, x.size(1), self.hidden_size).to(device)
    cx = torch.zeros(num_layers, x.size(1), self.hidden_size).to(device)

    for i in range(x.size()[0]): # for each time step
        hx, cx = self.lstm(x[i], (hx, cx)) # output hx/cx of shape (batch_size, hidden_size)
    
    return self.fc(hx[1])
```

The training loss:

```
Epoch [1/2], Step [100/600], Loss: 2.3095
Epoch [1/2], Step [200/600], Loss: 2.2956
Epoch [1/2], Step [300/600], Loss: 2.2852
Epoch [1/2], Step [400/600], Loss: 2.3077
Epoch [1/2], Step [500/600], Loss: 2.3027
Epoch [1/2], Step [600/600], Loss: 2.3133
Epoch [2/2], Step [100/600], Loss: 2.3056
Epoch [2/2], Step [200/600], Loss: 2.2853
Epoch [2/2], Step [300/600], Loss: 2.3103
Epoch [2/2], Step [400/600], Loss: 2.3044
Epoch [2/2], Step [500/600], Loss: 2.3034
Epoch [2/2], Step [600/600], Loss: 2.3049
```

I have gone through the code and attempt to fix it many times but still cannot find the problem. Could any one help? ;)